# Absolute position relative to some arbitrary element

Tags: css-position

Is it possible to make an element position absolute, relative to some special element? I'm talking about something more than the well known relative/absolute offers. Suppose this nested divs `#a > #b > #c > #d` each child of the previous. Now is it possible to make c's position absolute relative to a and d's position absolute relative to b? Or maybe even relative to some element that's not a parent of the element. Is it discussed anywhere? I guess it should be added in future versions of css if not present in current version.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose position:relative is given to #a and position:absolute #c then it will working but if you want position:absolute to #d relative to #c then it will not work. It will take position relative of #a.